# Border with Linear Gradient fill doesn't show border at run time

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Here is my XAML

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,1" StartPoint=".5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFf3f3f3" Offset="0.48"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFededed" Offset="0.51"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
```

I can see border at design time but it doesn't show at run-time. Why?

[image: Design Time as expected]
[image: Run time - can't see border]

Whats wrong with it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `BorderThickness`.